# Drupal date of Birth multiple select

Tags: drupal, forms

I want to create a form element that gonna output like this

**`select date:  [day] [month] [year]`**

and `each [box]` is select box ...

how can I do it with Drupal Form api 
I wouldn't want to use any fancy plugins / addons.

```
 $form['dob'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('select date:'),
  '#options' => array(1,2,3),
 );
```

outputs only

```
select date: [day]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can create 3 form items, and using theming to get the desired result.
- You can create your own form item which create 3 select boxes and a label with [`hook_elements`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_elements/6). This is somewhat time consuming.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Form API you can create 3 separate select elements to deal with the date selection. Be sure to set the form element's `#type` to `'date'`.

```
$form['date_select'] = array (
    '#title' => t('Date Selected'),
    '#type' => 'date',
    '#description' => t('Please select a date'),
    '#default_value' => array(
        'month' => format_date(time(), 'custom', 'n'),
        'day' => format_date(time(), 'custom', 'j'),
        'year' => format_date(time(), 'custom', 'Y'),
    ),
);
```

That should produce 3 select boxes for month, day and year.

Then in your submit function to output only the day reference it as such;

```
$form_state['values']['date']['day']
```